# Alternative to a lot of checkboxes

Tags: forms, html, interface, checkboxes, many-options

I need to give a user the ability to select (on/off) a subset of options from a list. There are over 100 of these choices to be made and the list will get longer. The data is not user friendly either. They are alphanumeric codes roughly 4 - 8 characters in length that would be practically impossible to remember. Essentially I need the user to easily be able to select a subset of these codes.

I can't imagine anything that would make this an enjoyable task for a user but is there possibly a more user friendly alternative to checkboxes?

Just for clarity the codes are for devices (i-1000 etc) that the user would like to be able to support.

Comment: Is it possible to provide some additional data along with the codes? This extra-data will help to filter and select sub-sets and give the sense to the codes as well.

Comment: Can you give us any more detail? This does sound like a very arduous task of the sort humans are terrible at. Can any of it be automated? Can any of it be groups/aggregated into larger chunks?

Comment: I agree with Alex: maybe you should try to improve the task itself, not the UI?

Comment: Okay so the client is a major phone manufacturer. They have hundreds of handsets. We need to target specific handsets based on their device codes. The subset might be very different each time. They do have more human legible names which I can and will present to the user. I may well be able to group them into smaller subsets.

Comment: So probably you could group the handsets by hardware  interface or some other features, which are significant while decision on support are made. Defenitelly, it's not the code but some features what lead the decision. The code is just shortcut in this case.

Comment: Yes this is true. The code is what is important to me but maybe not to the user. It may also be important to the user but it will surely help to use handset names. Grouping into sub groups seems to be key here. If the grouping is done properly the user may be able to include or exclude whole groups pretty easily. Thus getting down from 100+ interactions to 5 - 10 which would be MUCH better.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this excellent jquery plugin called [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and allow them to select from a dropdown and this plugin will ensure the ones which are selected are then removed from the list but highlighted in the selection.

[image]

This will scale even if the number of numeric codes increases and keeps the length of the form constant

**Note**: I know this will become a problem if the user selects a large number of values but then having so many values without specifying sub buckets for them is an information architecture problem.

Comment: I think, the problem still exists with this solution, as user should choose a lot of the items. So the main issue for me is to decrease the number of separate interactions (i.e. 100 -> 5).

Comment: I like this as a solution. I agree with Alexey though 100 items in one of there is still going to be a problem. Perhaps I can break the list up into smaller groups and have a few of these multi selects.

Answer (score 2):

Why not break up the long list into sections? Then you could use accordion-type functionality to allow users to expand/collapse as needed.

Example of look and usage here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

[image: Accordion menu]

As an optional extra, you could write a list [updated in real-time] of the selected items in another part of the screen, or at the bottom. This would allow the user to track which items then have selected without have to review the entire list (which is presumable longer than a single page).

Answer (score 1):

You could have...

- a left-hand column which has a (hopefully small) list of the collections of codes with checkboxes next to them
- a right-hand column which has the full list of every individual code

When the user checks a checkbox for a collection, it will automatically scroll to the individual codes and check them (and optionally flashes a color to alert the user that they've been selected). If a user unchecks a code, then it automatically unchecks the collection to inform the user that the entire collection is not selected.